# Power factor improvment c/k ratio

Tags: capacitor, power-factor-correction, reactive-power

All power factor improvment controller has a setting c/k ratio. Their manual says it is the lowest step of capacitor bank. It controls switching threshold. But how what is its significance?

Answer (score 1):

\$C/K = \frac{Q }{I1/5A * U_{LL} * 1.73}\$

Where Q     = Size of 1st step in VARs   (Capacitor smallest step)
      \$U_{LL}\$    = line-to-line voltage in volts
      I1/5A = CT ratio

Comment: Why it is used as switching threshold?

Comment: It is a control system gain ratio of negative reactance of cap VARs to positive reactance sensed by CT of inductive current loads such when this ratio is controlled PF is closer to unity and efficiency is improved.  But when you change it is more complex

Comment: In my pfi controller c/k is 0.13 & ct ratio 400/5. Does that mean capacitor step will change if inductive current change 0.13A?

Comment: No this is a ratio, not in units of Amps.

Comment: Why I have to define this ratio to a controller. What it does with it?

Comment: Actually I know the equation but I want to know the significance.

Comment: It is like calibrating the LSB on a DAC except here the 1st step is in VARs and there are limited steps.  How significant is the resolution on a DAC?

Comment: Thanks Tony Stewart. Can  you show me a calculation like DAC. For example a digital value 1023 means 5V. From which I can calculate the voltage for digital value 1 or whatever it is. C/k is threshold for changing step  of capacitor. Now suppose my controller is trying to change power factor from 0.96 to 0.98. Then it will add capacitor or just stay with that power factor depends on c/k ratio. In that case it must do some calculation & compare it with c/k. I just want to know that calculation.

Comment: I dont know, but i imagine CT current is measured by amplitude in + reactive axis only so that -ve reactive VAR current for each step of  cap bank and there are only so many steps of VAR correction and averaged over time so as not to switch too often. C/K is the gain ratio applied to CT reactive current detected.